# OpenShift Origin installation - No Attribute 'oo_glusterfs_to_config'

Tags: openshift-origin

I am getting the following error while installing openshift origin with ansible : " fatal: [console.isreehari.io]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'oo_glusterfs_to_config'"} "

I am using the "https://github.com/gshipley/installcentos" inventory file.

Thanks,
Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently broken and is fixed in https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/pull/3945